# Cake pattern: one component per implementation, or one component per trait?

Tags: scala, cake-pattern

I'm currently working to use the cake pattern on my application.

On exemples I have found across the web the exemples are kind of basic but doesn't involve more complex needs. What I'd like to do is not so fancy: I would like to have inside a cake pattern application, 2 services of the same type, using different implementations.

```
trait UserServiceComponent {
  self: UserRepositoryComponent =>
  val userService: UserService

  class DefaultUserService extends UserService {
    def getPublicProfile(id: String): Either[Error, User] = userRepository.getPublicProfile(id)
  }

  class AlternativeUserService extends UserService {
    def getPublicProfile(id: String): Either[Error, User] = call webservice here for exemple...
  }
}

trait UserService extends RepositoryDelegator[User] {
  def getPublicProfile(id: String): Either[Error, User]
}
```

It works fine if I use one implementation of the `UserService` at a time, but if I need both implementations in the same time, I don't really know how to do it.

Should I create 2 distinct components? Each one exposing a different userService value name? (defaultUserService/alternativeUserService). Using one component for both implementation I don't know how other components would be able to know which implementation is used when using the name `userService` since there are 2 distinct implementations in my application.

By the way, as the component expresses the dependency to the `UserRepositoryComponent`, while it is not needed by all implementations, I find it a bit weird to have only one component right? 
Imagine I don't want to build the full application which needs both implementations, but I need, for tests, to build only the AlternativeUserService which doesn't need the `UserRepositoryComponent`, it would be weird to have to provide this dependency as it will not be used.

Can someone give me some advices so that I know what to do?

Kind of related question:
[Cake pattern: how to get all objects of type UserService provided by components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532428/cake-pattern-how-to-get-all-objects-of-type-userservice-provided-by-components)

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First things first, you should decouple the `UserServiceComponent` from the implementations of `UserService`:

```
trait UserService extends RepositoryDelegator[User] {
  def getPublicProfile(id: String): Either[Error, User]
}

trait UserServiceComponent {
  val userService: UserService
}

trait DefaultUserServiceComponent extends UserServiceComponent { self: UserRepositoryComponent =>
  protected class DefaultUserService extends UserService {
    def getPublicProfile(id: String): Either[Error, User] = userRepository.getPublicProfile(id)
  }
  val userService: UserService = new DefaultUserService
}

trait AlternativeUserServiceComponent extends UserServiceComponent {
  protected class AlternativeUserService extends UserService {
    def getPublicProfile(id: String): Either[Error, User] = call webservice here for exemple...
  }
  val userService: UserService = new AlternativeUserService
}
```

If that looks verbose, well it is. The cake pattern is not particularly concise.

But notice how it solves your problem about having a dependency to `UserRepositoryComponent` even when not actually required (such as when only using `AlternativeUserService`).

Now, all we have to do when instantiating the application is to mix either `DefaultUserServiceComponent` or `AlternativeUserServiceComponent`.

If you happen to need to access to both implementations, you should indeed expose two userService value names. Well in fact, 3 names, such as:

- defaultUserService for the `DefaultUserService` implementation
- alternativeUserService for the `AlternativeUserService` implementation
- mainUserService for any `UserService` implementation     (the application chooses which one at "mix time").

By example:

```
trait UserService extends RepositoryDelegator[User] {
  def getPublicProfile(id: String): Either[Error, User]
}

trait MainUserServiceComponent {
  val mainUserService: UserService
}

trait DefaultUserServiceComponent { self: UserRepositoryComponent =>
  protected class DefaultUserService extends UserService {
    def getPublicProfile(id: String): Either[Error, User] = userRepository.getPublicProfile(id)
  }
  val defaultUserService: UserService = new DefaultUserService
}

trait AlternativeUserServiceComponent {
  protected class AlternativeUserService extends UserService {
    def getPublicProfile(id: String): Either[Error, User] = ??? // call webservice here for exemple...
  }
  val alternativeUserService: UserService = new AlternativeUserService
}
```

Then you can instantiate your cake like this:

```
object MyApp 
  extends MainUserServiceComponent 
  with DefaultUserServiceComponent 
  with AlternativeUserServiceComponent 
  with MyUserRepositoryComponent // Replace with your real UserRepositoryComponent here    
{
  //val userService = defaultUserService
  val mainUserService = alternativeUserService
}
```

In the above example, services that explicitly want to access the `DefaultUserService` would put `DefaultUserServiceComponent` as a dependecy of their component (same for `AlternativeUserService` and `AlternativeUserServiceComponent`), and services that just need *some* `UserService` would instead put `MainUserServiceComponent` as a dependency. You decide at "mix time" which service `mainUserService` points to (here, it points to the `DefaultUserService` implementation.

Comment: Nice thanks! By the way, should I always instantiate the service inside the component like you did? Or at mix time? What are the pros and cons? For MainUserServiceComponent I guess you couldn't instantiate it with the default because it would require the dependency to the DefaultUserServiceComponent right?

Comment: Yes, in general you should instantiate (or in any case implement the method returning the service) the services in the component, as their raison d'être is precisely to provide a specific service instance. For `MainUserServiceComponent` I did it when wiring everything up mainly by convenience, but I could very well have adhered to the cake pattern here too by defining `DefaultAsMainUserServiceComponent extends MainUserServiceComponent { _: DefaultUserServiceComponent  => val mainUserService = defaultUserService }` (and same thing with an `AlternateAsMainUserServiceComponent` trait).

Comment: +1, Good answer! @SebastienLorber One pro of instantiating all of your services in `MyApp` also includes having a single spot that configures the module, similar to a Guice module. In the end it's more or less a stylistic concern.

Comment: That's what I thought. In the end I start to understand pretty well this cake thing :) thanks all