# Delaying trait initialization

Tags: scala, constructor, initialization, traits

I need a smart mechanism for component composition which allows mixed in traits to initialize *after* the composed component. The following throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
class Component {
  def addListener(pf: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]) {}
}

trait DynamicComponent {
  protected def component: Component

  component.addListener {
    case x =>
  }
}

class Foo extends DynamicComponent {
  protected val component = new Component
}

new Foo  // -> NullPointerException
```

The following things are *not options* for me:

- Using `protected lazy val component`; that would produce an **avalange** of dozens of vals needing to become lazy, something **I do not want**.
- Putting `addListener` in a method, e.g. `initDynamic()`; because I will be mixing in many traits, and I don't want to remember to call half a dozen `initFoo()` methods.
- Using `DelayedInit`. This doesn't work with traits, at least according to the scaladocs.

I could live with a single `init()` call, but only under the following conditions:

- all mixed in traits can easily declare to be invoked in this one single call
- it is a compile error to forget the `init()` statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can delay the initialization of a trait by by using **early definitions**. (See section 5.1.6 of the [scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf))

```
class Foo extends {
  protected val component = new Component
} with DynamicComponent
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that possibility. Unfortunately in my use case, I am having an extra indirection: I have like `AbstractFoo extends DynamicComponent` and `Foo extends AbstractFoo`, where the component is provided by `Foo` and its paint methods _call into_ methods provided by `AbstractFoo`—using the early definition, `Foo` doesn't see any methods from `AbstractFoo` any more. Hmm....

Answer (score 2):

It's even clunkier than your solution, but you can always require the creation of a val that must be set with the `init()` method.  You *could* choose to not do it last and get an error at runtime, but at least you won't forget it entirely:

```
class Component {
  def addListener(pf: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]) {
    println("Added")
  }
}

trait Dyn {
  protected def component: Component
  protected val initialized: Init
  class Init private () {}
  private object Init { def apply() = new Init() }
  def init() = { component.addListener{ case x => }; Init() }
}

class Foo extends Dyn {
  protected val component = new Component
  protected val initialized = init()
}
```

No cheating!:

```
> class Bar extends Dyn { protected val component = new Component }
<console>:12: error: class Bar needs to be abstract, since value
initialized in trait Dyn of type Bar.this.Init is not defined
       class Bar extends Dyn { protected val component = new Component }
```

The advantage this has is if you need multiple things to be in place before you initialize all of them cooperatively, or if your `Component` class is `final` so you can't mix in anything else.

Answer (score 1):

AN idea could be to use the trick described here:
[Cake pattern: how to get all objects of type UserService provided by components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532428/cake-pattern-how-to-get-all-objects-of-type-userservice-provided-by-components)

All your components that should be initialized could be registered in some `Seq[InitializableComponent]`. And then you could initialize all registered components with a foreach.

No component will be forgotten in that Seq because they are registered automatically, but you can still forget to call the foreach anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea (I am happy to read about other suggestions):

```
class Component {
  def addListener(pf: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]) {
    println("Added")
  }
}  

trait DynamicComponentHost {
  protected def component: Component with DynamicPeer

  protected trait DynamicPeer {
    _: Component =>
    addListener {
      case x =>
    }
  }
}

class Foo extends DynamicComponentHost {
  protected val component = new Component with DynamicPeer
}

new Foo
```

So basically I am forcing the component to mix in a type that can only be provided by the mixed in trait. Reasonable? Looks a bit too complicated in my eyes.