# Scala: Example use for early definition / early initializer / pre-initialized fields

Tags: scala, traits

Scala allows you to make early definitions like so:

```
trait A {
  val v: Int
}

class B extends { val v = 4 } with A
```

What is an example use of this feature?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer/4712492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the value is used for the trait initialization. So for eaxmple for this trait:

```
trait UsefulTrait {
  val parameter : Int
  private val myHelperObject = new MyExpensiveClass(parameter)
}
```

The parameter is used to substitute for a constructor parameter. However the parameter should be rather made an abstract method, because it leaves more free space to the implementer.

Comment: OK, I see. But what is an example when it *shouldn't* be made an abstract method? Simply when you want to ensure this value doesn't change?

Comment: @gzm0 It is not necessary that the trait declares something to be a `val`. The problem may occur whenever it accesses _any_ abstract member during its initialization, because an implementing class may choose to use a `val` there. [See this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251379/delaying-trait-initialization)

Answer (score 2):

Let's see a example from the *Programming in Scala* book (page 451). If we have a definition like this:

```
trait RationalTrait {
   val numerArg: Int
   val denomArg: Int
}
```

Then numerArg and denomArg are called abstract vals & the trait can be used directly without extends, like this:

```
val x = new RationalTrait {
   val numerArg = 1
   val denomArg = 2
}
```

Or

```
val y = new {
   val numerArg = 1
   val denomArg = 1
} with RationalTrait
```

The above two are both valid *Pre-initializing* of abstract val in trait, **except** that when you need to put an expression value to abstract vals, **you can only use the later form**, like this:

```
val z = new {
  val numerArg = 1 * x
  val denomArg = 2 * x
} with RationalTrait
```

Another interesting example in book is to Pre-initialized fields in a class definition.

```
class RationalClass(n: Int, d: Int) extends {
  val numerArg = n
  val denomArg = d
} with RationalTrait {
  def + (that: RationalClass) = new RationalClass(
    numer * that.denom + that.numer * denom,
    denom * that.denom
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In unit tests in particular, you are interested on testing traits in isolation. In this case, you need to create an Object mixed in with the trait you are interested. This is an example:

```
trait Display {
  def show(msg: String) = ...
}

val o = new Object with Display
o.show("hey!")
```

Another scenario is when your trait depends on injected variables:

```
trait Logging {
  val stream: java.io.OutputStream
  def log(msg: String) = ...
}

val o = new { val stream = new FileOutputStream(...) } with Logging
o.log("hey!")
```